# Get value from multiselect in Java

Tags: javascript, java

I am using the multi-select dropdown. I want to send it a value into my Java code using setter and getter.

The code is like:

```
        <select id="CodeId" name="CodeId" multiple="multiple" class="3col active">

            <%
                PortalTO PortalTO=null;
                if(List!=null && List.size()>0){
                    for(int i=0; i<List.size(); i++){
                        PortalTO = (PortalTO) List.get(i);
                        if(FilterTO.getSubPortalId()==PortalTO.getCodeTO().getCodeId()){
                            selected="selected";
                        }else{
                            selected="";
                        }
            %>

            <option value="<%=PortalTO.getCodeTO().getCodeId()%>" <%=selected%>>
                <%=CBLUtil.checkNull(PortalTO.getCodeTO().getCode())%>
            </option>

            <%
                }
            }
            %>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

As a multi-select return array, so I set one setter and getter of type array, but I am unable to get it on my application end.

Comment: You're really not meant to use raw Java in JSPs anymore...

Comment: @Makoto List contains the values which I want to show into that drop down and if it equals to PortalTO.getCodeTO().getCodeId() then it will mark it as selected otherwise unselected

Comment: You should separate the logic because your code is unreadable.

Comment: You need to realize that JSP simply gets converted to HTML and in turn gets loaded into Browser that is on different machine than your application. In order to send data back to your application from JSP you need to use HTML forms (with POST) or AJAX.

Comment: I Used JS And ajax to solve this problem Thank You, Guys.

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged with [JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info)?